# Error when uploading files consecutively with .net core 6

Tags: c#, .net, file, asp.net-core, upload

Error when uploading files consecutively with .net core 6
I'm getting Error - Access Denied 403 Error.

I'm using Plesk Panel

Edit: Turn off ModSecurity on Plesk. It's works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off ModSecurity on Plesk.